# Moving index of an array and then freeing it

Tags: arrays, c, memory, struct, allocation

I am reading from a file and then putting it into a struct. While I'm reading the names, I am also checking for duplicate names and then testing to see if their ID's are greater than the other. If it is greater, then I am moving the greater entry ID down to replace it and then freeing the smaller entry ID. However, when I free the smaller entry ID (the one I don't want), it frees both memory locations.

Below I have my GDB tester showing my problem with memory locations more in detail:

```
89                              cards[upd_j - 1] = cards[j];
1: cards[0]->name = 0x55555555a688 "Stolen by the Fae"
2: cards[1]->name = <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x10>
3: cards[2]->name = 0x55555555a898 "Eternal Isolation"
4: cards[3]->name = <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x91>
5: cardsaccum = 2
6: j = 2
7: num_entries = 3
8: upd_j = 2
(gdb) n
91                          free(cards[upd_j]->start);
1: cards[0]->name = 0x55555555a688 "Stolen by the Fae"
2: cards[1]->name = 0x55555555a898 "Eternal Isolation"
3: cards[2]->name = 0x55555555a898 "Eternal Isolation"
4: cards[3]->name = <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x91>
5: cardsaccum = 2
6: j = 2
7: num_entries = 3
8: upd_j = 2
(gdb) n
92                          free(cards[upd_j]);
1: cards[0]->name = 0x55555555a688 "Stolen by the Fae"
2: cards[1]->name = 0x55555555a898 "\020\220UUUU"
3: cards[2]->name = 0x55555555a898 "\020\220UUUU"
4: cards[3]->name = <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x91>
5: cardsaccum = 2
6: j = 2
7: num_entries = 3
8: upd_j = 2
```

Here is my struct:

```
typedef struct card
{
    char* start;
    unsigned int id;
    char* name;
    char* cost;
    unsigned int converted_cost;
    char* type;
    char* text;
    char* stats;
    enum rarity rarity;
} card_t;
```

Code:

```
#include "card.h"
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void parser(struct card **cards,int i, char *pointer);

// FUNCTION FOR QSORT()
int cmpname (const void *pa, const void *pb) {
    const card_t * const *p1 = pa;
    const card_t * const *p2 = pb;
        return strcmp((*p1)->name, (*p2)->name);
}

// FOR OUTPUTTING THE RARITY WITH A CHAR
const char *rarities[] = { "common", "uncommon", "rare", "mythic" };

int main(int argc, char **argv) {   
    int padding;
    ssize_t result;
    int num_entries = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int cardsaccum = 0;
    int boolean;
    
    FILE *input_file;
    
    if((input_file = fopen(argv[1], "r")))
    {
        card_t **cards = malloc(sizeof(*cards));
        
        // getline() STORES THE LINE IN BUF
        char *buf = NULL;
        size_t bufsiz = 0;
    
        // SKIPS HEADER LINE
        getline(&buf, &bufsiz, input_file);
        
        // WHILE THE FILE STILL HAS TEXT
        while ((result = getline(&buf, &bufsiz, input_file)) != -1)
        {       
            //if (boolean != 1)
            //{
                num_entries++;
                
                // ALLOCATES MEMORY
                cards = realloc(cards, sizeof(*cards) * num_entries);
                cards[cardsaccum] = malloc(sizeof(card_t));
            //}
            
            boolean = 0;
            
            // STORE CHARACTERS OF BUF IN ARRAY
            char *array = strdup(buf);
            // MAKE COPY OF ARRAY TO MAKE CHANGES TO 
            char *stringp = array;
            
            // COPIES MEMORY ADDRESS TO FREE LATER ON 
            cards[cardsaccum]->start = array;
            
            // SEPERATES FILE WHEN , IS FOUND
            cards[cardsaccum]->id = atoi(strsep(&stringp, ","));
                
            stringp++; 
            cards[cardsaccum]->name = strsep(&stringp, "\"");;  
            
            
            //TESTING FOR DUPLCIATES
            for (int j = 0; j < cardsaccum; j++)
            {
                //CHECK IF CURRENT = PREVIOUS
                if (strcmp(cards[cardsaccum]->name, cards[j]->name) == 0)
                {
                    // ID > THAN PREVIOUS?
                    if(cards[cardsaccum]->id > cards[j]->id)
                    {
                        // FREE CARD AT POSITION J
                        free(cards[j]->start);
                        free(cards[j]);
                        cards[j] = NULL;
                        // GET THE REST OF THE INFO FOR THE CORRECT ENTRY
                        parser(cards,cardsaccum, stringp);
                        
                        j++;

                        int upd_j = j;
                        // FREEING THE LESSER CARD ID
                        cards[upd_j - 1] = cards[j];    
                        free(cards[upd_j]->start);
                        free(cards[upd_j]);
                        cards[upd_j] = NULL;
                        // NO NEED TO ACCUM SINCE WE FREED ONE CARD
                        num_entries--;
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        free(cards[cardsaccum]->start);
                        free(cards[cardsaccum]);
                        cards[cardsaccum] = NULL;
                        num_entries--;
                    }
                    //  IF DUPLICATE IS FOUND, SET BOOLEAN TO 1
                    boolean = 1;
                    break;
                }   
            }
            
            // IF NOT DUPLICATE
            if (boolean != 1)
            {
                parser(cards,cardsaccum,stringp);
                cardsaccum++;
            }
        }
        
        if(boolean == 1)
        {
            cards[cardsaccum] = NULL;
        }

        // QSORT
        qsort(cards, cardsaccum, sizeof(*cards), cmpname);  
            
        for(i = 0; i < cardsaccum;i++)
        {
            padding = strlen(cards[i]->name);
            padding = 51 - padding;
            printf("%-s %*s\n", cards[i]->name, padding, cards[i]->cost);
            printf("%-*s %*s\n", 43, cards[i]->type, 8, rarities[cards[i]->rarity]);
            printf("----------------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("%s \n", cards[i]->text);
            printf("----------------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("%*s\n", 52, cards[i]->stats);
            printf("\n");
        }
            
        for(i = 0; i < cardsaccum; i++)
        {
            free(cards[i]->start);
        }
            
        for(i=0; i < cardsaccum ;i++)
        {
            free(cards[i]);
        }
        free(buf);
        free(cards);
        
        // CLOSING FILE
        fclose(input_file); 
        
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "./parser: cannot open(%s%s%s): No such file or directory\n", "\"", argv[1], "\""); 
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a step by step with gdb to check what happens ?
Can you shared an input file triggering the issue ?

Comment: I haven't investigated your code in detail, so I don't know where the error occurs, but I think the code would be easier if you did things sequentially: (1) Read all cards, don't care about duplicates for now. (2) Sort the cards by name. You are going to do that anyway. Now all cards that are the same are next to each other. (3) Go through the array and filter it, so that you keep only the highest id from a block of identical cards. (You can expand your sorting criterion, so that for equal strings, the hightest ID is always the first card.)

Answer (score 0):

When you find a duplicate at position `j` and you want to keep the new card at `cardsaccum`, you should:

- "destroy" (i.e. free all resources of) the card at `j`;
- put the new card into slot `j`.

You shouldn't do anything to the adjacet cards, so please forget about that little dance that you do with `upd_j` and `j++`.

Your code should look like this:

```
if(cards[cardsaccum]->id > cards[j]->id)
{
    // destroy old card
    free(cards[j]->start);
    free(cards[j]);

    // copy current card
    cards[j] = cards[cardsaccum];;
        
    // complete parsing current card
    parser(cards, j, stringp);

    num_entries--;
}
```

In general, your code is a bit complicated. For example, why have both `num_entries` and `cardsaccum`, which are basically the same thing, only that you update them in different places.

As I've already said in comments, I think the following strategy would be easier to implement:

- Read all cards, don't care about duplicates.
- Sort the cards by name or perhaps by name first, by id second.
- Filter out the duplicates, which now are all adjacent.

I also recommend to write a destructor function for your cards, so that you don't have to write

```
free(cards[j]->start);
free(cards[j]);
```

all the time. A destructor will come in handy when you add more things you need to `free` when you destroy the card.